# Creating a RAID-5 using Storage Spaces in Windows 11

Tags: windows, raid, windows-11, raid-5, storage-spaces

I want to try the new Storage Spaces in Windows 11. Some years ago I bought an external enclosure with 5-bay for hard drives and also provide RAID 5 functionality out-of-the-box. It works pretty good and no issue. This time I want to mount another RAID 5 but using the built-in Storage Spaces available in Windows 11.

My previous RAID5 was using 5 HDD with 8 TB each, so the total available was 32 TB (29.1 in reality).

My new RAID5 will be with 6 HDD with 8 TB each, that's suppose to be 40 TB from what I understand (or ~35 GB in reality).

I started creating an Storage Pool in Windows 11 and then associated all the 6 storage drives
Then my options from what I understand are

- Resiliency type: Parity
- Total pool capacity: 43.6 TB
- Available pool capacity: 43.6 TB
- Size (maximum): 29.0 TB
- Including resiliency: 43.5 TB

[image: capture with default options]

Supposedly the Size is auto-calculated depending of Total pool and Resiliency type, but my question is why is so low? The size will be less than my current RAID5 with 5 disks, it should be more with 6 disks.

If I change the size to the correct value I get

- Size (maximum): 36.3 TB
- Including resiliency: 54.4 TB

[image: capture with updated options]

I don't know if I am doing something wrong or I don't fully understand this. If I create the Storage with the default options effectively it creates a new Disk but with less size than my current Storage. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

so you are seeing total capacity of 29TB because roughly 33% of storage space is usually allocated for backup capacity. 43.6*67% = 29.21 TB.

Additionally, you can achieve higher parity storage space using 5 disks using Powershell but the Storage Spaces UI in WIN10/11 lacks some functionality for adding the total number of columns for the RAID. By default, the number of columns is set to 3.

3 Columns is fine for 3 disks, but for 6 disks you need the column set to 6. 3 Columns means, data is stripped over first 2 disks and parity data sent over to the 3rd.

In your 6-disk parity storage space, the column count of 3 sacrifices the capacity of remaining disks. So when working with 6-disks, you must use Powershell to create the storage space and you must specify the column count when doing so.

This command will create a new storage space on an existing pool of 5 physical disks

```
New-VirtualDisk -StoragePoolFriendlyName "Storage Pool 1" -FriendlyName "StorageSpace1" -ResiliencySettingName Parity -NumberOfDataCopies 1 -NumberOfColumns 6 -ProvisioningType Fixed -UseMaximumSize -Verbose
```

The code above will only create the storage space without any volumes. Remaining process must be completed from the Storage Spaces UI or through PowerShell commands to create a volume and bring it online.

```
Get-VirtualDisk StorageSpace1 | Get-Disk | Set-Disk -IsReadOnly 0
```

Get-VirtualDisk StorageSpace1 | Get-Disk | Set-Disk -IsOffline 0
Get-VirtualDisk StorageSpace1 | Get-Disk | Initialize-Disk -PartitionStyle GPT
Get-VirtualDisk StorageSpace1 | Get-Disk | New-Partition -DriveLetter “D” -UseMaximumSize
Initialize-Volume -DriveLetter “D” -FileSystem NTFS -Confirm:$false -NewFileSystemLabel “FooBar”

Documentation for you to review: [MS Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/mt243829(v=ws.11)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#task-1d-decide-whether-to-store-backups-on-the-same-storage)

[Capacity%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56EJS.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi, that applies to Windows 11 also? I don't find any option to enable or disable backup in Storage Spaces... The articles it seems is mainly for Windows Server 2012

Comment: Was unable to find any documentation specifically for Win 11 but this applies more or less. Added some PowerShell commands for your reference to the answer.